# Ejecutar código en otro ordenador

Tags: python

tengo un código escrito con *python* y guardado como (*.pyw*). Me gustaría saber si hay algún modo de poder ejecutarlo en otro ordenador sin tener que instalar todas las librerías que utilizo en el código. Gracias.

Comment: Para mi, la pregunta no es duplicada, pero bue, la comunidad habló... La unica forma que conosco de lograr eso es convertir el programa en un exe.

Comment: @DanteS. Consideras que la pregunta debe ser reabierta?

Comment: @Christian Yo creo que si, debería ser reabierta, ya que OP NO está preguntando como crear un exe, si no como ejecutarlo en otra compu sin necesidad de instalar todas las librerías. Capaz exista una solución que NO implique convertir el programa en un exe.

Comment: @DanteS. listo he votado por su reapertura

Comment: @Christian hasta donde sé, si la pregunta fue cerrada por el usuario `Comunidad` significa que el mismo autor aceptó que su pregunta es duplicada.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem bueno eso no lo sabía. Entonces dejémoslo ahí